# Router required for Virgin Media modem

Tags: router, wireless

I'm adding Virgin Media broadband to a new office with up to 14 users (worst case). The modem will have 5 static IP addresses and Virgin Media have said that the modem will be in modem only mode, i.e. no routing and a separate router would need to be purchased (this is as a consequence of the static IP addresses)

Is there anything I need to consider when finding a router and can anyone suggest a router? Some of the PCs will not have WiFi cards attached so 5 or 6 network ports on the router would be handy.

Comment: Do you have public web servers?  What needs public routing?  (I.e. why 5 routable static IP’s?).

Comment: It just came with the package that's been bought. We currently only need one in reality.